# My Dell computer microphone doesn't work in windows but works in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, microphone

I am using DELL latitude E5530 non-Vpro computer, i installed both Ubuntu 19.04 and windows 10 19H1 in separate partitions. I have updated all the drivers including sound and microphone. but in Ubuntu I can use built-in Microphone to record voice or call on Skype and etc... But in windows it prompts that you don't have microphone. My computer has one place for headphone at right bottom of computer with Headphone ICON.
I updated the driver hundreds of time. I installed a fresh copy of windows and updated the driver again but still i have the problem.
Note! No external microphone works too.

Comment: Under Microphone, do you have 'Allow access to the microphone on this device' set to On?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes I allowed

Comment: Are you using Dell SupportAssist to update the drivers? Or are you downloading from some 3rd party site?

Comment: @spikey_richie I downloaded from Dell.com